# Docker daemon fail to run 'MASQUERADE': No such file or directory

Tags: iptables, docker

I have some issue to install and run the docker daemon on Ubuntu 21.04.

During the install of the packages I am getting this bit of fail message :

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-03-26 15:59:32 UTC; 13ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 47139 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 47139 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to get a bit more information on the issue I ran `dockerd --debug` and get this :

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to Setup IP tables: Unable to enable NAT rule:  (COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE' failed: iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): Couldn't load target `MASQUERADE':No such file or directory
```

I tried to purge the entirety of docker that's installed, reboot and retry the installation but I am getting the same.

I also tried to reinstall `iptables` like this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables` but it gives out the same fail as the installation of docker:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/430 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 121818 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../iptables_1.8.7-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking iptables (1.8.7-1ubuntu2) over (1.8.7-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up iptables (1.8.7-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-hirsute) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-03-26 16:04:24 UTC; 9ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 47622 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 47622 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 26 16:04:24 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am running Ubuntu from a USB stick on a Chromebook laptop using [Breath](https://cb-linux.github.io/breath/) if it can help with my situation.

I thought that maybe `docker0` wasn't setup but it seems to be here when running `ip link show` :

```
lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp0s12f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether cc:f9:e4:cc:10:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c9:dc:1a:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Is there something that I have done wrong ? or something related to my setup ?